# Every Second Person?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from an article on UN website: who.int/news/item/18-03-2021-ageism-is-a-global-challenge-un

***Every second person*** in the world is believed to hold ageist attitudes

Does the part in bold mean half of people or everyone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are quoting this document from the UN https://www.un.org/development/desa/ageing/uncategorized/2021/03/ageist-attitudes-held-by-half-of-the-worlds-population-cause-serious-social-and-economic-ills/  **Remember to cite and link to your source of each quote**

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of that and I have added the link of the source.

Comment: [The page you link to](https://www.who.int/news/item/18-03-2021-ageism-is-a-global-challenge-un) doesn't contain that sentence. The first sentence begins: "Every second person in the world is believed to hold ageist attitudes". Is that what you meant to copy?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to copy. I have copied the exact words in my question now.

Answer (score 4):

If this is from the source that I linked to in comments, it is explained in the notes in the source:

> Prevalence figures based on a survey of 83 034 people in 57 countries found one in every two people held moderately or highly ageist attitudes (i.e. stereotypes and prejudice). More information: https://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/17/9/3159

"Every second person" is another way of saying half of all people.

Comment: It is from this article: https://www.who.int/news/item/18-03-2021-ageism-is-a-global-challenge-un

Comment: Emma-Li, you should have given that information in your question.

Comment: You will also hear, *Every other person,* to mean the same thing.

Comment: The original meaning of decimation (Latin: decimatio; decem = "ten") was a form of Roman military discipline in which **every tenth man** in a group was executed by members of his cohort (military unit). (Wikipedia)

Answer (score -1):

This is colloquial, and neither numerically accurate nor precise. Read it as "Many people - too many - have ageist attitude."

Relevant citation: [***Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online***, *every second year/person/thing etc*, definition (b)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/every-second-year-person-thing-etc)

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke of my boyhood about the Boy Scout who took the oath of membership which included a promise to be 'friends with every other scout' and then went down the line of scouts kicking every second one (as I understand it) on the shins.

Comment: I think 'every second person' meaning 'many - too many' is wildly non-standard. Could it be a mistranslated idiom? It does remind me of the casual UK 'half of', meaning 'a lot of', e.g. 'Half [of] the people in Birmingham are inbred'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It's common enough (possibly US only) that LDoCEO includes it, and I've heard it used that way in NYC. Whether it means "...too many..." tends to be contextually-dependent; "Every second person in Appalachia is inbred" doesn't carry the "too many" implication, whereas "Every second person in the barrio is an illegal immigrant" does carry it.

Comment: I can imagine saying 'Every second person I met at the Linux event had a neckbeard', even if it wasn't strictly numerically accurate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - ...which was sort of the point behind my answer, especially the comment about "...neither numerically accurate nor precise...".

Comment: I think the point got caught in my neckbeard.